# Error : this.state.joblistings.map is not a function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on project, I fetch some data from live API . In console the Data is coming from Server but when I set this data in `div` to show for user It give me error that `this.state.joblistings.map is not a function` . Could you please help me how to solve this problem. I will also share code with you.

```
    class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          joblistings: [],
          initial:0

        }
      }
      async componentDidMount() {
        try {
          console.log("mounted")
          const response = await fetch(`...../api/joblistings/CTcG9kN8kGtsLvtbg`);
          const json = await response.json();
          console.log(json);
          this.setState({ joblistings: json });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }}

      homeView(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({initial:1})
      }
  render() {
    if(this.state.initial === 1){
        return (<HomePage/>);
      }
    return (
      <div>
          <Header />
          <br/><br/>
          <h1>Hello from index</h1>
          {this.state.joblistings.map(item => <div key={item._id}>{item.job.contractType}</div>)}
        <Btn onClick={this.homeView}>
          Proceed
        </Btn>
      </div>
    );
            }
  }
```

Comment: The response from `const json = await response.json();` is most likely an object, not an array.

Comment: because `.map()` belongs to Arrays.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Could you suggest any solution please ?

Comment: @Jai Could you suggest any solution please ?

Comment: @Jon can you post the response. What is it object or something else?

Comment: @Jai  `{company: {…}, job: {…}, rect: Array(5), success: true}`

Comment: @Jon Well I'm not sure why you're `await`ing the fetched response. It looks like you're trying to map on a promise. I would `const response = await fetch(`...../api/joblistings/CTcG9kN8kGtsLvtbg`);` then `console.log(response)` and see what the response looks like. I assume your `json` is on `response.body`

Answer (score 1):

As you posted the response you got. That is an object and `.map` can't iterate over it. Instead you can push this object in the desired property:

```
const response = await fetch(`...../api/joblistings/CTcG9kN8kGtsLvtbg`);
const json = await response.json();
console.log(json);
let joblistings = [json];
this.setState({ joblistings });
```

Comment: `this.setState({ joblistings });` didn't this help?

Comment: data is showing in console but I want to display it in div

Comment: `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: I used ` {this.state.joblistings.map(item => <div key={item._id}>{item.joblistings}</div>)} `

Comment: @Jon in the posted response i don't see any property respective to `_id` but i assumed that prop `job` do have some expected props. So, i guess if it is not there *`_id`* then it should be undefined and it would set for multiple elements. That is where it says it should be unique.

Comment: Could you please suggest me what I may used to show all data which is coming from server